# Date Range filtering not populating table Angular Material

Tags: angular, typescript, date, filter, angular-material

I am trying to filter my table based on the date ranges selected and when I hit the submit button, the table is empty and there is no filtered data in the console log. I have tried doing this a few different ways with no luck. I also have a search filter that works, until I put in the dataSource.filter='' + Math.random(). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

TS

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { MatSort} from '@angular/material/sort';
import {MatPaginator} from '@angular/material/paginator';
import {MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogConfig } from '@angular/material';
import { DialogDataComponent } from "../dialog-data/dialog-data.component";
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import {FormControl, FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';


export interface User {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  distributor: string;
  storeNum: number;
  poNum: number;
  createDate: Date;
  recDate: Date;
  totalUnits: number;
}


@Component({
  selector: 'app-order-table',
  templateUrl: './order-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./order-table.component.scss']
})
export class OrderTableComponent implements OnInit{
  [x: string]: any;
  public users: User[];

  private usersUrl = 'api/users';


  displayedColumns: string[] = ['name', 'distributor', 'storeNum', 'poNum', 'createDate', 'recDate', 'totalUnits'];
  pipe: DatePipe;
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<User>(this.users);


  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: false}) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort, {static: true}) sort: MatSort;

  filterForm = new FormGroup({
    fromDate: new FormControl(),
    toDate: new FormControl(),
});

  get fromDate() { return this.filterForm.get('fromDate').value; }
  get toDate() { return this.filterForm.get('toDate').value; }

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, public dialog: MatDialog) {};


  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getUsers().subscribe(data => this.dataSource.data = data)
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    console.log(this.dataSource);


  }

  getUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.http.get<User[]>(this.usersUrl)

  }

  openDialog(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogDataComponent, new MatDialogConfig())
  }

  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

  applyFilter(search: string, start: Date, end: Date) {

    this.dataSource.filter = search.trim().toLocaleLowerCase();
    this.pipe = new DatePipe('en');
    this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data, filter) =>{

      if (start && end) {
        //1. Need to determine why filtered data wont push to the table
        return data.createDate >= start && data.createDate <= end;

      }
      return true;
    }
    //2. Need to determine what is being filtered/filter value
    this.dataSource.filter= ''+Math.random();
}
}
```